# Flexbox column children stretching the page instead of utilising overflow-y

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My problem is that the discussion columns (red and green) are stretching the page out instead of stretching to the height of .content and keeping that way. While I could set the height of the discussion boxes to a fixed height, I'd much rather try and make the most of whatever the user's screen space provides instead, preferably without a JS hack if I can.

My only thought right now is perhaps absolute positioning html, body AND content, but again if I can avoid doing that then great, as it'll probably come back to bite me later on.

Has anyone got any suggestions on this one? Or should I just resolve myself to an absolute positioning?

Here's the sample: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eprYKo

I've kept the markup there nice and simple with none of the fluff, there's a bit more to my actual markup but the essence of it is there

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
  Header.
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="discussion">
    <h4>Discussion Title</h4>

    <div class="comments"> <!-- Should scroll. -->
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="other-discussion">
    <h4>Discussion Title</h4>

    <div class="comments"> <!-- Should scroll. -->
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.discussion, .other-discussion {
  background: red;
  width: calc(50% - 40px);
  margin: 20px;
}

.other-discussion {
  background: green;
}

.comments {
  overflow-y: auto;
  color: white;
}

.comment {
    padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, If you can provide your code or your link, that will help someone to answer your question

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to tack that on the end, added it now.

Comment: Overflow only takes effect when the element is limited in height/width. This doesn't seem to be set here.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. In my actual implementation I have stuff about the comments div, so I can't just do height: 100% as the stuff above it can also be variable in height.

Comment: You'll need to give some more info. You want the comments to start scrolling at some point, so how is their height constrained? It seems like what you want is straightforward enough with (nested?) flexboxes but you leave out the necessary details in your description.

Comment: I'm not sure what more I can detail really. Nothing here can have a fixed height, that's part of the problem. The comments are constrained to what's remaining of the height of the two debate holders, which are based on remaining height in the body plus some margin at the bottom.

Comment: @BenWoodford [Does this codepen](http://codepen.io/woestijnrog/full/YyOqzQ/) resemble what you want? Don't be shy to give detailed feedback.

Comment: @woestijnrog that's pretty much it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@woestijnrog posted [this](http://codepen.io/woestijnrog/full/YyOqzQ/) CodePen which resolves the issue I was having.

[Permalink to Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33368280/flexbox-column-children-stretching-the-page-instead-of-utilising-overflow-y?noredirect=1#comment54840048_33368280)

HTML

```
<div id='wrapper'>
<div class="header">
  Header.
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="discussion">
    <h4>Discussion Title</h4>
 <div class='stuff'>stuff</div>

    <div class="comments"> <!-- Should scroll. -->
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="other-discussion">
    <h4>Discussion Title</h4>
    <div class='stuff'>other stuff</div>

    <div class="comments"> <!-- Should scroll. -->
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
      <div class="comment">Foo.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 85vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding-bottom: 50px;
    }
    .header {
        height: 100px;
        background: blue;
        margin: 20px;
    }
    h4 {
    }
    .content {
        flex: 1;
        display: flex;
        flex-basis: 45%;
        justify-content: space-around;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .stuff {
        background: #ccc;
    }
    .discussion .stuff {
        flex: 0 0 60px;
    }
    .other-discussion .stuff {
        flex: 0 0 150px;
    }
    .discussion, .other-discussion {
        background: red;
        width: calc(50% - 40px);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .other-discussion {
        background: green;
    }
    .comments {
        color: white;
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
    .comment {
        margin: 25px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do `html, body { height: 100% }` that will make the page the height of the document. Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but here is an updated pen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avGdpm